# binary sum through <bitset> and HEX

Tags: c++, binary, hex, bitset

I'm trying to build a simple BIN -> HEX converter using a class, I would like to save it later in a header file for eventual need <.<" .

It kinda works. Kinda because I have some output, but I cannot understand what is happening when it prints X. Why Am I getting those else exceptions ? I should get only 4 bit combinations..

I'm trying to learn. Sorry for eventual stupid code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

class Hash{
private:
    char stringa[150];
    int byteCount=0;

public:

//call to get a string
void getStringa(){

    char temp_char;
    std::cout << "Write a string and press enter to continue" << std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
        temp_char = std::cin.get();
        if(temp_char == '\n'){
            stringa[i] = '\0';
            byteCount = i;
            break;
        }
        stringa[i] = temp_char;
    }
}

char nibbleToHEX(std::bitset<4> x){
    char HEX;

    if(x == 0000) return HEX = '0';
    else if (x == 0001) return HEX = '1';
    else if (x == 0010) return HEX = '2';
    else if (x == 0011) return HEX = '3';
    else if (x == 0100) return HEX = '4';
    else if (x == 0101) return HEX = '5';
    else if (x == 0110) return HEX = '6';
    else if (x == 0111) return HEX = '7';
    else if (x == 1000) return HEX = '8';
    else if (x == 1001) return HEX = '9';
    else if (x == 1010) return HEX = 'A';
    else if (x == 1011) return HEX = 'B';
    else if (x == 1100) return HEX = 'C';
    else if (x == 1101) return HEX = 'D';
    else if (x == 1110) return HEX = 'E';
    else if (x == 1111) return HEX = 'F';

    else return 'X';
}

//call to encode string to 256 binary digits and then go HEX a nibble at a time

void encodeStringa(){
    std::cout << "converting  |" << stringa << "|  to binary: \n";
    char HEXSTRINGA[64];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
        if(stringa[i] == '\0') break;
        std::bitset<4> x(stringa[i]);
        std::cout << x;

        HEXSTRINGA[i] = nibbleToHEX(x);


    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "You used " << byteCount << " bytes.\n";
    std::cout << "You still have " << 64-byteCount << " bytes." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Converted string in HEX form: " << HEXSTRINGA << std::endl;

}


};

int main() {

    Hash BCHAIN;

    BCHAIN.getStringa();
    BCHAIN.encodeStringa();


    return 0;
 }
```

Some test IO is:

```
**Teststring**
0100010100110100001101000010100111100111
XXBXBXA3XF
```

X is an error at least for what I am trying to do..
I don't get it why, I would expect random combination of 4 bits for some chars.. because I only have 15 combinations with 4 bits. Not an X ... is an overflow issue?

Comment: Better use [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) maybe?

Comment: **Be cautious:** `0001` integer literals with leading zeroes are interpreted as octal numbers!

Comment: I think I will rewrite the nibbleToHex function so that I can have in input a variable bitset<p>  x with p variable in bases of 2. I have noticed that when I receive SPACE or other char not defined it occurs in the error. So if I use a bitset with p as 16 I should manage to get a UNICODE conversion .. or I am wrong?

Comment: I'm quite curious what you think comparing a `bitset` to the number one thousand does.

Comment: I will probably be wrong...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thx for the advice <.<"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do much simpler by simply combining four subsequent characters into a number:

```
char const* const digits = "0123456789abcdefg"; // or upper case, if you prefer

for(auto i = x; i < byteCount; i += 4)
//           ^: to be considered later!
{
    unsigned int n
        = (stringa[i + 0] == '1') << 3
        | (stringa[i + 1] == '1') << 2
        | (stringa[i + 2] == '1') << 1
        | (stringa[i + 3] == '1') << 0;

    HEXSTRING[pos++] = digits[n];
}
```

So far I did *not* consider a letter not being either `'0'` or `'1'` – leaving this to you!

One thing yet open is the number of input digits *not* being a multiple of 4!

Well, above I started with some unspecified `x`, remember? I'd prefer filling up the lacking digits with leading zeros, i.e. considering e.g. `110011` as `00110011`:

```
size_t pos = 0;
unsigned int n = 0;
size_t offset = byteCount % 4;
if(offset != 0)
{
    size_t o = offset - 1
    for(size_t i = 0; i <= o; ++i)
    {
        n |= (stringa[i] == '1') << (o - i);
    }
    HEX_STRING[pos++] = digits[n];
}
```

And now we start above loop at this offset:

```
for(auto i = offset; i < byteCount; i += 4)
{
    // ...
}
```

For this working correctly you yet need to set the `byteCount` appropriately. You do so if the string is shorter than 150 characters. You might set it to 150 before entering the loop – but what, if input string is even longer? You'd get inappropriate results!

You might want to prefer reading into a `std::string` instead!

```
std::string stringa;
std::cin >> stringa;
```

This will stop reading a string at the first whitespace occurring. You might instead use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) if you want to handle input like `00 11` as well (you'd do so with your current solution, but you do not skip the whitespace).

With either approach you then can use `stringa.length()` instead of `byteCount`, the latter being dropped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you wrote in `nibbleToHEX` are not binary but decimal (not beginning with zero) and octal (beginning with zero)

If you want to use binary string, you should use `std::bitset`:

```
#include <string>

char nibbleToHEX(std::bitset<4> x){
    char HEX;

    if(x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0000"))) return HEX = '0';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0001"))) return HEX = '1';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0010"))) return HEX = '2';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0011"))) return HEX = '3';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0100"))) return HEX = '4';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0101"))) return HEX = '5';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0110"))) return HEX = '6';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("0111"))) return HEX = '7';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1000"))) return HEX = '8';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1001"))) return HEX = '9';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1010"))) return HEX = 'A';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1011"))) return HEX = 'B';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1100"))) return HEX = 'C';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1101"))) return HEX = 'D';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1110"))) return HEX = 'E';
    else if (x == std::bitset<4>(std::string("1111"))) return HEX = 'F';

    else return 'X';
}
```

Or `0b` prefix (since C++14):

```
char nibbleToHEX(std::bitset<4> x){
    char HEX;

    if(x == 0b0000) return HEX = '0';
    else if (x == 0b0001) return HEX = '1';
    else if (x == 0b0010) return HEX = '2';
    else if (x == 0b0011) return HEX = '3';
    else if (x == 0b0100) return HEX = '4';
    else if (x == 0b0101) return HEX = '5';
    else if (x == 0b0110) return HEX = '6';
    else if (x == 0b0111) return HEX = '7';
    else if (x == 0b1000) return HEX = '8';
    else if (x == 0b1001) return HEX = '9';
    else if (x == 0b1010) return HEX = 'A';
    else if (x == 0b1011) return HEX = 'B';
    else if (x == 0b1100) return HEX = 'C';
    else if (x == 0b1101) return HEX = 'D';
    else if (x == 0b1110) return HEX = 'E';
    else if (x == 0b1111) return HEX = 'F';

    else return 'X';
}
```

My recommendation is using an array (string literal is an array):

```
char nibbleToHEX(std::bitset<4> x){
    unsigned long idx = x.to_ulong();
    if (idx < 16) {
        return "0123456789ABCDEF"[idx];
    } else {
        return 'X';
    }
}
```

Also you should initialize `HEXSTRINGA` in the function `encodeStringa`, or some junk may be printed after the hash:

```
    char HEXSTRINGA[64] = "";
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will try to do something.